# Probability to see at least 2 elements of a certain color in top 10 of rotating chain?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability to see at least 2 elements of a certain color in a closed chain (loop) of 100 elements when only 10 **successive** elements have this certain color? Only the top 10 elements can be seen and the chain rotates at a constant rate.
Just by counting, I got 17/100 times I see at least two of those elements. How do I calculate it?

Comment: The number of ten-link windows that can be seen is of course $100$. How many of them contain at least two coloured links? Well, the first possible window starts with 8 non-coloured and has 2 coloured at the end. Then you move on to 7+3, 6+4, 5+5, 4+6, 3+7, 2+8, 1+9, 0+10, $\ldots$ .. And in the end you have a window that **starts** with two coloured and ends with 8 non-coloured. So how many windows did I list here?

Comment: Your count is correct.  The top position you see must either be in one of the eight positions before the first link of that color or in one of the first nine positions of that color.